# Regex - Escape all the minus signs that don't introduce a switch for a command line utility

Tags: regex, command-line, escaping, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a [small script](http://www.xyplorer.com/xyfc/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=12054) that takes a string in input and feeds it to a command line utility. This utility supports the use of certain switches too, which are introduced by the minus sign (-). In order for such utility to work properly, all the minus signs that aren't part of a switch must be escaped with double quotes. And to make life and syntax easier for the end user, I can take care of the escaping process programmatically, by **finding all the minus signs that are not part of a switch with a regex**.

The possible switches of such utility are: `-r -i -w -p -h -n -s --help`

I can partially identify all the minus signs of interest with the following regex:

```
\B-(?![riwphns]\b)
```

(the `\B` is needed because the `-` must appear either at the start of the input or after a blank space, the `\b` because after the letter of the switch there's either a blank or a EOL)

As you can see, **I currently can't deal with `--help`**. How could I tweak the regex above to solve this? (possibly staying in the realm of elegant one-liners) Mind, the regex engine that I'm using **doesn't support lookbehind**.

Some test cases:

```
NO ESCAPE
rainbow-
rainbow-what
rainbow-that
-n 100
-h
gotham -s
gotham -p batman
blah --help
*.txt -n 5

ESCAPE
-what
ulysses's -
jordan -what
883 - la
-f trooper
---help
bam -help
-holp
```

EDIT: the command line utility in question is es.exe, the CL interface to Everything (http://www.voidtools.com/download.php, for Windows). The reason behind my question is to make the syntax of a query via es.exe as similar as possible to the same one made via Everything.

Answer (score 0):

For Unix-based commands, you can specify `--` as the argument between your flags and the list.

For example, let's say there was a file named `--help`; to remove it, you would have to do this:

```
rm -vf -- --help
```